# CSS Design Issue while Error displayed

Tags: html, css

I got an design issue while an error is displayed. The best thing is to see it for yourself by opening the below link and then wait for 5 seconds

http://newsmartwave.net/magento2/porto/demo2_en/?SID=a35991641fe6db0203301e75c77d5919

Then you are able to see a popup. Click on the Go button, An error will be displayed and the GO button is placed differently.

[image]

How can i fix that the GO button stays on the same place as before the error is shown?

This is what I have tried

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
    <form class="form subscribe"
          novalidate
          action=""
          method="post"
          data-mage-init='{"validation": {"errorClass": "mage-error"}}'>
        <div class="field newsletter">
            <div class="control" style="float: left;">
                <input name="email" type="email" id="footer_newsletter"
                       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="actions" style="float: right; width: 1%; margin-right: 70px;">
                <button class="action subscribe primary" title="Go" type="submit">
                    <span>Go</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Mind to share some code ?

Comment: Added code @SylvainAttoumani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
div.mage-error[generated] {
    margin-top: 38px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 84px;
}
```